# Pandas resample column based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a similar dataframe:

```
x | y
1 | 1
3 | 1
3 | 1
4 | 1
5 | 2
5 | 2
9 | 2
8 | 2
```

And I want to resample this dataframe such that x values with the same y value is averaged. In other words:

```
     x       |    y
(1+3+3+4)/4  |    1
(5+5+9+8)/4  |    2
```

I've looked into the [pandas.DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) function, but not sure how to do this without timestamps.

Comment: looks like a [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might return what you're looking for:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"x":[1,3,3,4,5,5,9,8],"y":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]})
df.groupby(["y"]).mean().reset_index()
```